# oracle improve query performance

Tags: sql, performance, oracle, select

I'm new to oracle and I have to fight against this problem.

I have a table with approximately 520 millions of rows inside. I have to fetch all rows and import them (denormalizing) inside a NoSQL db.

The table has two integer fields C_ID and A_ID and 3 indexes, one over C_ID, one over A_ID and one on both fields.

I've tried this way at the beginning:

```
SELECT C_ID, A_ID FROM M_TABLE;
```

and this has never given to me any result in reasonable time (I had no possibility to measure the time because it seemed to never complete).

I changed the query in this way:

```
SELECT /*+ ALL_ROWS */ C_ID, A_ID FROM (SELECT
    rownum rn, C_ID, A_ID
FROM
    M_TABLE WHERE rownum < ((:1 * :2 ) +1 )) WHERE rn >= (((:1 -1) * :2 ) +1 );
```

I run this query in parallel using 3 threads and paginating using pages with size 1000.

I tried to introduce three optimization:

1) I created statistics over the table:

```
ANALYZE TABLE TABLE_M ESTIMATE STATISTICS SAMPLE 5 PERCENT;
```

2) I partitioned the table in 8 partitions.

3) I created the table with parallel option.

Now I am able to fetch 10000 rows per second and so the whole process takes about 15 hours to complete (the DB is running on a 4 cores, 8 GB machine).

The problem is that I need to complete all in maximum 5 hours.

I am out of ideas and so, before I ask for a new machine, you know any way to improve performance in such a situation.

Comment: Indexes do not help here. You are full scanning the table. And I don't understand how that pagination helps you. it won't work.

Comment: I think the real optimization I have done consists in the query change.

Comment: Sorry I retract the asertion about the query with pagination, it may work, but **sure** you do more work than needed, reading first blocks every time. You'll have speed at begining but you'll finish very slow.

Comment: yes, I noted this; the process is very quick in the first pages and it becomes slow and slow going on.
Have you any suggestion to avoid this?

Comment: you said your table has 8 partitions. Why you don't insert with 8 threads reading from specific partition? if you insert 520 millions / 8 at a time it crash something?

Comment: I have to try it now; I used only 3 thread because I am running the query from another machine that has only 2 cores.

Comment: How much time is spent fetching data from the relational DB and how much time is spent inserting into the NoSQL DB?  Have you profiled your app?

Comment: At the moment I not still writing inside the NoSQL DB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What do you do with your result? Is it fetched directly to a file with PL/SQL or do you use another application to process the data? Is it sent accross the network? (this might be the low hanging fruit).

The reason I ask is that usually a `FULL SCAN` (without an ORDER BY) will **return the first rows instantly**. If you're outputting the result to a file you should see it start to fill up immediately. If you do not, this means that there is a lot of empty space at the beginning of the segment, which could explain why the query never returns (in a reasonable time at least).

So when you say that your query doesn't return I'm a bit concerned, how can you tell? Does the following block returns?

```
DECLARE
  l NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  FOR cc IN (SELECT C_ID, A_ID FROM M_TABLE) LOOP
    l := l + 1;
    EXIT WHEN l >= 100000;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

If it does it means that your FULL SCAN is being processed. By timing the above query you should be able to calculate how much time would be needed for a complete single SCAN, assuming the segment is uniformly dense.

Reading 500M rows is a lot of work but the rows are tiny so if the table segment is well compacted Oracle should return all rows in a reasonable time. Table segments can have inefficient space configuration if repeatedly deleted then loaded with `INSERT /*+APPEND*/` for example. Rebuilding the table ([`ALTER TABLE MOVE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_3001.htm#i2081902)) will remove all empty useless space in the segment. By the way when you partitioned the table you did rebuild it, so this may be the reason why your query now returns !!

In any case I would advise you to retry the FULL TABLE SCAN, possibly after having rebuilt the table to reset any empty space and the high water mark. A single FULL TABLE SCAN is by far the most reliable method (and one of the most efficient) to access lots of data.

If you need to further improve performance, I suggest you take a look at ROWID partitionning ([DIY parallel processing](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:39946845137685) scheme) or the built-in package [`DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_parallel_ex.htm#CHDIJACH).

Comment: As an addition to this, you could look in V$SESSION_LONGOPS while the full scan is running to see how far through it is and how long it is expected to take.

Comment: I'm fetching data using "libocci" library from a remote machine (in the same subnet)

Comment: Are you seeing rows being fetched with the FULL SCAN?

Comment: I moved again to this query:
    `SELECT  /*+ ALL_ROWS PARALLEL*/ channel_id, account_id FROM M_TABLE;`

And it seems to be working faster (also because I enabled `PARALLEL_AUTOMATIC_TUNING` on `SPFILE` scope).

Now, observing the, plan I see only "INDEX FULL SCAN" and "INDEX FAST FULL SCAN" on the table.

I used V$SESSION_LONGOPS as suggested to observe the query running and  I noticed that the process is really fast until the work reach the step "Sort Output"; this seems to be the bottleneck of the process.

Comment: Please post the complete query plan: you should not have a SORT step in your plan. The use of the index means that there are other columns in the table and Oracle chooses to FULL SCAN the index instead of the table because it takes less space.

Comment: I think I was looking at something wrong; you can find the plan here: [http://pastebin.com/tJY4N2GT](http://pastebin.com/tJY4N2GT).

In any case, I changed again my query and it seems to give me now results in about 5h and 20 minutes; here is the new version:

`SELECT /*+ ALL_ROWS PARALLEL*/ channel_id, account_id FROM (SELECT channel_id, account_id, rownum AS rn FROM M_TABLE) WHERE rn >= (((:1 -1)* :2) + 1) AND rownum <= :2`

I am using now pages with size 1000000.

I think that ROWID partitioning and the parallel processing enhanced using the schema you posted was the main help I received.

Answer (score 5):

Oracle is pretty intelligent in telling us where it had spent its time.  You can do this by tracing your session using Oracle's extended SQL trace (in other words 10046 trace).  Your query is extracting data from one table that has lot of data.  Check your IO rate (db_file_scattered_read) which is probably one of the top wait events of your query.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a bit of a drastic solution to try but you could look at table compression. In Oracle 10g this is only really useful for read-only tables since the block are uncompressed when write operations are done. I've found compression to be useful for large tables in a data warehousing environment.

It is also possible to just compress certain partitions so it you are adding data to the end of a table that is partitioned by date, you could compress historical partitions while leaving the most recent one uncompressed.

The advantage of table compression is that it reduces the amount of I/O required which could help on an I/O constrained system. I was often getting 10:1 compression out of tables although it depends on what is stored in the table and the sorting used when inserting data.

For an existing table I think you can use the command:

```
ALTER TABLE M_TABLE COMPRESS MOVE;
```

Note that this may help to solve your problem but changing the underlying structure of the tables might be a little drastic. Also, rebuilding the table as compressed can invalidate some of the indexes.

Under Oracle 11g you can also you advanced compression which allows updates to the data but this involves expensive licensing costs.

There is some documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/schema.htm#i36181) and a lot more information in [this PDF document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/partitioning/twp-data-compression-10gr2-0505-128172.pdf)

Comment: Good idea! Is the compression feature available on all DB editions?

Comment: @VincentMalgrat Not sure. Think it is available in all editions but not entirely sure. Oracle 11g Advanced Compression is at an additional cost but there is standard compression with I think comes with all editions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes as said by user2033072 you should use `SQL Trace` and `TkProf` to know a bit more about the query. You could see the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/sqltrace.htm).

Also, more simply you could use [`explain plan`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm), that way Oracle will show what it is planning to do.

Comment: I've never seen columns or column order affect index usage. Do you have any documentation reference to this behavior? He is selecting more than 12% of the rows in the table (all rows in this case as there is no predicate), so the optimizer will not use an index.

Comment: @Wolf Hi, you can see it here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/optimops.htm in the sections 13.5.3.6 Full Scans and 13.5.3.7 Fast Full Index Scans, there are also Hints if the optimizer doesn't consider it. It only works for indexes that contains all the data required in the query (as in this case).

Comment: I've previously read that if all the data is available in an index the optimizer may decide to not hit the table. I read the supplied notes, and then tried creating a big table and indexes and running several tests. I was able to get the optimizer to use a Fast Full Scan with the INDEX_FFS hint and no predicate if one column was Not Null (as documented), although the cost went up (which may not matter and not sure on execution time). However, the documentation and my testing made showed no difference on column order. Interesting.

Comment: I think you're right about the order. I suffered a lapsus. It matters only when in the where or ordering... I'm removing it from the answer.